# If $H<G$ ($G$ is a finite group) and $|G|=m|H|$, then for all $g\in G$ we have $g^{m!}\in H$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, and if $|G|=m|H|$, then for all $g\in G$ we have $g^{m!}\in H$.

The question suggests I adapt the proof of Lagrange's Theorem in the book (*Groups and Symmetry*, MA Armstrong). Below is my attempt.

Assume $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ and let $g\in G-H$. The map $g \mapsto gh$ for $h\in H$ is a bijection between $H$ and $gH$ and so $|H|=|gH|$. We can do this only so many times since there are only finitely many elements in $G-H$.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2):

Let G act on the set of left cosets of H via left multiplication. This action affords a homomorphism from G to $S_{m}$ with kernel K being contained in H. Let G be an arbitrary element of G, then gK is an element of the quotient group G/K whose order divides m!. Hence $(gK)^{m!} = K$, which implies that $g^{m!}$ is in K and hence it is in H.

Comment: no doubt your proof is very elegant!!, But just a thought: OP wanted to extend the proof he has for Lagrange's theorem. So not sure if this is beyond what he has been exposed to so far.

Comment: I think it is fair to offer an alternative argument especially when the OP has already been offered what he had asked for perhaps he will be inspired to look up the definition of a group action in case he doesn't know this already.

Comment: @Daniel Akech Thank you for this elegant argument even though group actions come later in my course. But I always appreciate novel ways of looking at problems.

Comment: Jacopo Stifani, for group actions, I recommend you self-study the following beautiful expository notes by Morandi and Conrad: http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/groupactions.pdf; http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/gpaction.pdf

Comment: @Daniel Akech Thank you for the links. I've already downloaded the PDFs for future self-study. On a cursory glance, they look succinct and to the point, but no exercises! lol.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your last statement will lead you to the conclusion you want to arrive at.

**Idea:** (which can be generalized easily)

Suppose $|G|=3|H|$, then consider $g \in G$.

1. If $g \in H$, then for sure $g^{3!} \in H$.
2. If $g \not\in H$, then $gH$ is a coset different from $H$. Then ask yourself, where is $g^2$? It cannot be in $gH$, so it must be in $H$, hence $(g^{2})^{3}=g^{3!} \in H$.
3. If $g^2 \not\in H$, then $H,gH,g^2H$ are distinct cosets. Ask where is $g^3$?

Hope this will help you generalize.

Comment: You make it look so easy I'm embarrassed. Thank you for this idea.

Comment: Do you think I can turn this into an induction argument?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Here is a formalization of your argument using group theory.

The set of left cosets $G/H$ has $m$ elements. Therefore its group of permutation $P$ has order $m!$. The map $f_g:G/H\to G/H:kH\mapsto ghK$ is a bijection, therefore $f_g \in P$. So we have that $f_g^{m!}=Id_P$.

It follows that $f_g^{m!}(H)=g^{m!}H=H$. Therefore $g^{m!}\in H$.

Comment: This look really nifty. I still have not been introduced to cosets, so I will keep this in my back pocket until that day comes. Thanks so much.